# How to include validation of select field in this function?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have this form:

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Address Information</legend>

<div>
<label for="country">Country:</label> <span id="country-list">
<select name="country" class="required">
<option value="0">Please Select</option>
<option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">American Samoa</option>
</select>&nbsp;</span>
<span class="error_msg" style="display: none; ">
<br><label for="space">&nbsp;</label>Please select your country.</span>
</div>

<div>
<label for="street-address">Street Address:</label> <input type="text" id="street_address" name="street_address" value="" size="50" class="required">
<span class="error_msg" style="display: inline; "><br><label for="space">&nbsp;</label>Please enter your accurate street address (at least 7 characters)</span>
</div>

<div>
<label for="suburb">Suburb:</label> <input type="text" name="suburb" value="" class="required">
</div>

<div>
<label for="city">City:</label> <input type="text" id="city" name="city" value="" class="required">
<span class="error_msg" style="display: inline; "><br><label for="space">&nbsp;</label>Please enter your city (at least 4 characters)</span>
</div>

<div>
<label for="post-code">Post Code:</label> <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode" value="" class="required">
<span class="error_msg" style="display: inline; "><br><label for="space">&nbsp;</label>Please enter your postal code (at least 3 characters)</span>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
```

I have a jquery function below that when submit is clicked, it checks only the `input text fields` but not the select field. It will return either true if fields has values and false if there is a field that has no value.

```
function ValidateForm()
{
   jQuery('span.error_msg').hide();
   var success = true;

     jQuery("#shippingF .required").each(function()
        {
            if(jQuery(this).val().length <= 2)
            {
                jQuery(this).next().show();
                success = false;
            }
     });

    return success;
}
```

How can I include the select field on this simple validation function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, sorry I was thrown off by some errors in the original code, here is the final working version

```
function ValidateForm()
{
 jQuery('span.error_msg').hide();
 var success = true;

 if($('select[name=country]').val() == '0'){
   success = false;
  }
     jQuery(".required").each(function()
      {
        if(jQuery(this).val().length <= 2)
        {alert(jQuery(this).val().length);
            jQuery(this).next().show();
            success = false;
        }
 });

return success;
}
```

A couple of notes on the original code:

1. Could not find the selector Id `shippingF`, so I had to remove that and reference by class `.required`, if you define that somewhere up in the hierarchy then it should be fine
2. removed the class `.required` from the select element so it would not be included in your each loop. This will always return 1 and cause your if statement `if(jQuery(this).val().length <= 2)`
    to fail.

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RNSvX/1/)

Comment: This will just check first the select field. How if the select field has `0` value and the other fields are empty? then only the error message of the select field will be displayed instead off error messages for each empty input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can include another evaluation into the loop and check if its a select:

```
function ValidateForm()
{

   jQuery('span.error_msg').hide();
   var success = true;

   jQuery("#shippingF .required").each(function()
   {

       if(jQuery(this).hasClass('select')) {
          if(jQuery(this).val() == 0) {
             success = false;
          }
       } else {
          if(jQuery(this).val().length <= 2) {
             jQuery(this).next().show();
             success = false;
          }
       }
   });
   return success;
}
```

Something along those lines.